# Invoke New-LocalUser command with a variable as the password

Tags: powershell

I'd like to have a script that creates a local user based on choices from the user.

I currently do it by putting the command in a variable then I invoke it.

```
$pw = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$command = "New-LocalUser -Name $name -Password $pw $accountparam $accexpiredate $passwordparam $pwexpiredate $canchangepwparam"

iex $command
```

Everything is working fine except the password, the command fails with the following error :
**Unable to convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value from the "System.String" type to the "System.Security.SecureString" type**

If I remove the password parameter and let PowerShell automatically ask it then it works, but I'd like to manually ask it.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why are you using iex? Looks like its trying to convert your securestring to a string

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it, here is the solution in case someone is asking himself the same question and finds this

```
$command = "New-LocalUser -Name $name -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString '$pw' -AsPlainText -Force) $accountparam $accexpiredate $passwordparam $pwexpiredate $canchangepwparam"
```